# Is the following Haskell implementation of quicksort efficient?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, quicksort

I found the following implementation of quicksort in the book titled Learn You Haskell.

```
quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]  
quicksort [] = []  
quicksort (x:xs) =   
    let smallerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]  
        biggerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a > x]  
    in  smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

My question is, doesn't this undermine the efficiency of quicksort given that

1. The ++ operation is rather expensive
2. List comprehension is used to construct the two sublists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an algorithmic point, it is not an in-place algorithm. Hence, it will not be as efficient as the traditional imperative implementations that you know. (Being in-place is a crucial aspect of the superb performance of quicksort-like sorting algorithms.)

It will run with quicksort's typical complexity (on average `O(N * log(N))` with worst case `O(N²)`). Thus, it is efficient in the sense that it will be able to scale with inputs. But it will not be as fast as highly tuned implementations (e.g. see [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/180417/76071)).

As a minor tweak, I remember replacing `[x] ++ biggerSorted` by `(x:biggerSorted)` was a low-hanging fruit to improve the performance slightly. That was many years ago, so perhaps optimizing compilers today can do that low-level optimization automatically.

Comment: Quicksort is O(n^2), it is only O(n log n) if the pivots are favorable.

Comment: @Noughtmare And on already-sorted lists, the chosen pivot is never favorable.

Comment: It's safe to say, though, that the *expected* run time is O(n lg n); it's the hidden constant that increases when you implement partitioning with new lists rather than swaps.

Comment: @Noughtmare fixed: I clarified the statement on complexity to mention the worst case.

Comment: GHC is indeed smart enough to turn `[foo] ++ bar` into `foo:bar` these days.